# How to sync multiple outlook calendars

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I am facing a conundrum where I have 3 outlook accounts (I work for multiple clients, that require private outlook accounts for email and meeting scheduling) and I need to sync the 3 of them.

I can use overlay mode to at least view what is on my list for the day, but the problem is one person will schedule a meeting in my 'open' time, which is booked on  another calendar. I have been copying meetings back and forth, but I easily have 30 meetings a week, and this becomes at least an hour of overhead each day.

Is there some sort of method to sync these calendars/exchange accounts?

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, there is no built-in option available to automatically sync all your calendars in Outlook. As an alternative, let's say the three accounts are A, B and C, for Account A, create a rule to forward all meeting invitations to B and C. Do the same thing for Account B and C to forward meetings to the other two accounts:
[image]

Comment: What if I create a meeting? Do I need to create it in all three? Send it to myself as an invitation?